# Press Option+Command+8 on mouse button 6 click - Lua Logitech G hub

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I have a G102 mouse, middle button is 6

```
  if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6
    then
      OutputLogMessage("Gesture button pressed")
        PressKey(firstKey)
        Sleep(20)
        PressKey(secondKey)
        Sleep(20)
        PressKey(thirdKey)
        Sleep(20)

        ReleaseKey(firstKey)
        ReleaseKey(secondKey)
        ReleaseKey(thirdKey)
        end
```

Problem is i don't know scan codes for OPTION+COMMAND+8 keys. There's a smart zoom functionality in MacOS for this key combination. How can i find these scan codes, manual doesn't have it.

Comment: Try `PressKey("lgui")` for "Command" (Win key) and `PressKey("lalt")` for "Option" (Alt key)

Comment: Scan codes are not LGS-specific.  MacOS should have some program to display scan codes.

Comment: BTW, you can create usual macro for this key combination (without writing Lua code at all), and then run this macro from Lua code by `PlayMacro("YourMacroName")`